# SEM with skipped questions in survey

Tags: missing-data, survey, structural-equation-modeling, methodology

I have conducted a survey on social media. One of the questions asks if you ever use a chatforum. If they answer "no" they skip question 2-5. Thus, I will have missing data despite that they are not actually missing.

Some information about my study:

I am measuring 5 variables (usage, informativeness, attitude, community, playfulness). Each variable is measured with x number of items (=questions). The issue is for the community which I measure with 4 items (question 2 till 5). But if they answer "no" in the first question, then they skip question 2 till 5.

A lot of people have skipped question 2 till 5 because they don't use chat forum. How can I still conduct the analysis. I am using Structural Equation Modelling using stata and amos.

Comment: Presumably answers to Q#1 are of interest to know the popularity of the forum. But that question also splits the sample in two. Suggest you analyze #2-5 separately--only for those saying Yes to #1. //  If there are additional questions #6, etc., of interest whether the subject uses the forum or not, then you need to think about the purpose of those. However, you may have already decreased subject interest in those questions among people answering No to Q#1, made not to feel among your target group, and being asked to skip questions.

Comment: Use full information maximum likelihood estimation for missing data.

Comment: Why you should consider them as missing values? if u treat them as missing values that means that they can probably take any plausibe value, but your are sure that the values in the 2 up to 5 questions for those who  do not use the forum are let say 1 or -1 or whatever u want.

Comment: Ok, so I keep the whole sample, replace the "missing values" with for example 999 to indicate that these were skipped due to the skip-logic. But if I use estimation techniques, let's say out of the 400 respondents, 80 have not answered question 2-5. But all 400 have answered all the other questions, so my only "missing data" is for questions 2-5 because they don't use chat forums.

From what I understand, using estimation models will just assume some values instead of the 80 people. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @LunaFaruq It depends on the scale of measurment of your items, again they are not missing, I think it is not appropiate if u  recode them as 999 and the other posible values 1 or 2 , u can think of them as neutral values take 0 i.e who did not use the forum can not judge it so it takes 0 and will be a new category

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "conduct the analysis" in the last ¶.  In particular, ¿what analysis do you want to do with the individuals that aren't participating in this chat?